# Memory leak of coordinate transformation functions with symbolic evaluation

Tags: memory, coordinate-transformation

Some functions like `ToPolarCoordinates` seems not to manage memory usage properly. As is compared to `Norm`:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Do[
  ToPolarCoordinates[{x, y, z}];
  Print@MemoryInUse[],
  3];
Do[
  Norm[{x, y, z}];
  Print@MemoryInUse[],
  3];
```

gives

```
96411880
96432720
96453368
96451496
96451496
96451496
```

I tried other coordinate transformation functions like `ToSphericalCoordinates` and find the same behavoir. Each call to these functions takes extra memory.

This is only found with symbolic evaluation. Numerical evaluation is OK:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Do[
  ToPolarCoordinates[{1, 2, 3}];
  Print@MemoryInUse[],
  3];
```

gives

```
96456792
96456792
96456792
```

What is happening to them? Tested on MMA 13.3.1.

Comment: In an interpreting language you always have a complete record in memory for inputs and their possible outputs. The interpreter does not look for identites of multiple attempts; such a routine input check would slow down the the system to velocity zero, because for any Enter it would mean to check the complete history.

Comment: @RolandF, I think the interpreter doesn't check the history. I have restricted the record size to zero, so the memory usage should not increase any more. As you can see, `Norm` is like that. But `ToPolarCoordinates` is not.